# Namespaces not found

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, minikube

I see the following error when I run my deployment:

`Error from server (NotFound): error when creating "n3deployment.yaml": namespaces "n2" not found`

My n3deployment.yaml has no reference to n2?

**Step By Step**

1. Ensure everything is empty

```
c:\temp\k8s>kubectl get pods
No resources found.

c:\temp\k8s>kubectl get svc
No resources found.

c:\temp\k8s>kubectl get deployments
No resources found.

c:\temp\k8s>kubectl get namespaces
NAME          STATUS    AGE
default       Active    20h
docker        Active    20h
kube-public   Active    20h
kube-system   Active    20h
```

2. Create files

```
n3namespace.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: n3

n3service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-n3
  namespace: n3
  labels:
    app: my-app-n3
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-app-n3

n3deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-n3
  labels:
    app: my-app-n3
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app-n3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app-n3
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: waiter
        image: waiter:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

3. Apply configuration

```
c:\temp\k8s>kubectl apply -f n3namespace.yaml
namespace "n3" created

c:\temp\k8s>kubectl apply -f n3service.yaml
service "my-app-n3" created

c:\temp\k8s>kubectl apply -f n3deployment.yaml
Error from server (NotFound): error when creating "n3deployment.yaml": namespaces "n2" not found
```

I used to have a namespace called `n2` but, as you can see, it no longer exists.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was missing to have executed before:

```
kubectl create namespace n3
```

Comment: While this works, better approach is to update yaml file responsible for namespace creation. That way it is much more reproducible and ready for production use.

Answer (score 3):

I had previously created two contexts and my minikube cluster was set to still be in the `n2` context. I deleted the context, re-ran the command and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Add namespace: n3    to deployment spec

Answer (score 1):

In my case I created context and set --namespace to not existing one, the solution was switch namespace only using the kubectl commands:

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=<namespace>
```

You can check if in your situation is the same problem using:

```
kubectl get svc -o wide
kubectl describe sa default | grep Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use kubens and kubectx to verify on which namespace and context you are after that verify your kubernetes manifest files

Answer (score 0):

In your n3deployment.yaml file add namespace as well under metadata section like below

```
n3deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-n3
  namespace: n3
  labels:
  app: my-app-n3
  ------
  -------
```